# How to update QML Tableview from c++

Tags: qt, qml

I have a model in c++. I want update Tableview when model changed. I have a problem. Model and  Tableview is different threads. I need a signal that reload page with QML Tableview

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I create new thread and new object. When doWork finished i emit signal with result